# ASP.NET Session State & Postback problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem that I believe is a session state issue, but I'm at a loss to figure out what's wrong.  I have a sample project to illustrate the problem.  (Code below)  I have 2 buttons.  Each populates a List with some unique data and then uses that data to add a row to a table.  The row contains text boxes so that the user can edit the data.  (For my sample, there's no update button to persist the data.)  To reproduce the problem in VS2010, create a new "ASP.NET Web Application" project and copy/paste the aspx code and the c# code-behind into Default.aspx, then run the application.

- Press the DataSet 1 button and the grid should populate with 1 row.
- Edit the data in one of the text boxes and tab off of the text box.  (The newly entered text should remian, and the font should be blue.  This is what I want to happen.)
- Now click either of the DataSet buttons to reset the List and refresh the table.
  Edit the data in one of the text boxes and tab off the text box.  (Immediately, the text in the box refreshes back to its original value.  This only happens once, though.  If you edit either text box now, it will work normally.)
- This is repeatable... the first edit after pressing the DataSet buttons a 2nd, 3rd, etc. time gets reset back to the original value.  And I can't figure out why.

---

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DebugPostbackIssue._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        Populate the table with DataSet #1:<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDS1" Text="Dataset 1" OnClick="btnDS1_Click" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Populate the table with DataSet #2:<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDS2" Text="Dataset 2" OnClick="btnDS2_Click" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblData">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" ID="thrData">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Column 1"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Column 2"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DebugPostbackIssue
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private List<string> _MyData = new List<string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSessionData();
            GenerateGrid(false);
        }

        protected void btnDS1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _MyData = new List<string>();
            _MyData.Add("111");
            _MyData.Add("aaa");

            SaveSessionData();
            GenerateGrid(true);
        }

        protected void btnDS2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _MyData = new List<string>();
            _MyData.Add("222");
            _MyData.Add("bbb");

            SaveSessionData();
            GenerateGrid(true);
        }

        private void SaveSessionData()
        {
            Session["MyData"] = _MyData;
        }

        private void LoadSessionData()
        {
            if (Session["MyData"] != null)
                _MyData = (List<string>)Session["MyData"];
            else
                _MyData = new List<string>();
        }

        private void GenerateGrid(bool ClearData)
        {
            if (ClearData)
                while (tblData.Rows.Count > 1)
                    tblData.Rows.Remove(tblData.Rows[tblData.Rows.Count - 1]);

            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            foreach (string s in _MyData)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();

                TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                txtBox.Text = s;
                txtBox.Attributes.Add("OriginalValue", s);
                txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
                txtBox.AutoPostBack = true;
                tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);

                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            }

            if (tr.Cells.Count > 0)
                tblData.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

        void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox Sender = (TextBox)sender;
            if (Sender.Text == Sender.Attributes["OriginalValue"])
                Sender.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            else
                Sender.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have it working, now.  Wizpert's answer pointed me in the right direction...  Upon discovering that the TextChanged event did not fire during the times when the value was erroneously being reset to the original value, it occurred to me that during the Click events I was calling GenerateGrid(true).  This forced the removal of the existing rows and the addition of new rows.  (Removing & adding the dynamic controls at that point in the life cycle must be interfering with the TextChange event handler.)  Since the Click event fires after Page Init and after Page Load, the state values were already written to the text boxes and I was overwriting them.  But the 2nd text box edit did not force GenerateGrid(true) to be called so the state values were not overwritten any more.

If this sounds confusing, I apologize.  I'm still wrapping my head around this.  But suffice to say that I had to change my GenerateGrid method to reuse any existing rows and not delete them.  (If they don't exist, like when GenerateGrid is called from Page Init, then they are added.)  So this was a page lifecycle issue after all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I took some time off of my work to compile your code, and I figured it out, just change your textbox change to the following :

```
 void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox Sender = (TextBox)sender;
            if (Sender.Text == Sender.Attributes["OriginalValue"])
                Sender.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            else
            {
                Sender.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                if (Session["MyData"] != null)
                {
                    List<string> _ss = (List<string>)Session["MyData"];
                    //_ss.Find(a => a == Sender.Attributes["OriginalValue"]);
                    _ss.Remove(Sender.Attributes["OriginalValue"]);
                    _ss.Add(Sender.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

ur welcome!

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't make any other changes?  When I try this, I still see the same results.

Comment: no I didn't :) thats all what it took , I can send u the code if you want

Comment: So I made this change and I still get the same results.  In fact, if I click on one of the buttons a second time then change a value in the textbox, the TextChanged event doesn't fire!  If I make another change to a text box, then the event fires from then on, until the first change after clicking on a button, again.  (I take it that you're event is firing every time?)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a datatable. I would, on "event" copy your asp table content to a datatable, then when you get the servers response add that to the datatable. Then copy the datatable back to your asp table, and repeat... Datatables can be used like variables.

Or try using a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing...

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSessionData();
            GenerateGrid(false);
        }
```

To...

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
{
     LoadSessionData();
     GenerateGrid(false);
 }
```

Based on your description I believe that your value is getting reset because of how the page life cycle works in ASP.NET & that is the page_init is getting called before your event due to ASP.NET quirkiness.  Above code is how I work around it, I'm sure there's other ways too.

Comment: This isn't working for me, either.  If I leave the parameter as False, I get 2 rows.  If I change it to True, then I'm always displaying the original data because I dropped and recreated the dynamic controls after the page loaded.  (I thought if I wait for OnLoadComplete, the dynamic controls are not created by the time that the session state is handled by ASP.NET.  Don't I need to recreate the dynamic controls in the Init event so that they exist when Load is triggered?)